# Extracting characters inside parentheses in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have a shapefile of the buildings on my college campus.  It has a "name" field that includes the name of the building and then in parentheses the building's campus address (i.e. Health and Counseling Services (71)).  I want to create a new field, "number", that is only the number within the parentheses (i.e. '71'). I am working in QGIS with regular expressions but I can't quite get it right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following `regexp_substr` expression matches a number in parentheses at the end of the line:

```
regexp_substr( "name", '.*\\(([0-9]+)\\)$' )
```

"Health and Counseling Services (71)" => 71